# Mass Transport and Ion Transport - Li-ion Batteries

Tags: electrochemistry, kinetics

I am new to the field and trying to grasp the theories/ physical phenomena behind the Li-ion batteries. I came across two phenomenons **'Mass transport' and 'Ion transport'**.

As I understood Mass transport is the Diffusion process (Fick's First law) which describe the transport mechanism how Li-ions are transported from one electrode to the other through the electrolyte.

Now, I wonder what is covered by the Ion transport equations which are based on Fick's Second law and Stokes-Einstein equation.

As I understood, they both describe the same thing [probabl two parts of the same phenomena which is Mass *(which is Li-ions)* transport through the electrolyte]. But I don't quite get it, Could someone please shed some light on this matter? Any explanation including explanation relating to physical phenomenon is much of my liking.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Nernst-Planck equation is predominately used to describe this

Comment: many thanks....any suggestions for books to learn electrochemical basics related to Li-ion batteries if you know some?

Comment: Honestly i just used Wikipedia. Learn the Nernst Equation, Butler Volmer Equation, Overpotential losses including concentration/reaction/ohmic losses, randles sevick equation & cortrell equation, Electrochemical impedance spectroscopy, Galvanic cells, electrolytic cells. For physical modeling you will need the essential Nernst-Planck eqn